# How would one record player kills in CS:GO using an external program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have been trying to write a small program that runs behind Counter-Strike: Global Offensive. The program must be completely external, as there is no way to access live match data or the API during a competitive ranked match. So far, the best approach I could find is as follows:

```
case WM_TIMER:
    COLORREF curColor, safetyColor;
    for(int a = 1750;a < 1830;a++)
        for (int b = 75;b < 100;b++)
        {
            curColor = GetPixel(csgoDC, a, b);
            safetyColor = GetPixel(csgoDC, 1856, 1060);
            if (GetRValue(curColor) == 255 && GetGValue(curColor) == 255 && GetBValue(curColor) == 255 && GetRValue(safetyColor) != 255)
                PlaySound(_T("C:\\headshot.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
        }
    break;
```

This is triggered by a timer. It does not work reliably, and I am fairly certain it won't work at all in fullscreen mode (Hard to test when it isn't reliable to begin with). The indices in the nested for loop correspond to the place on the screen where the killfeed shows up. Here is an example of the UI (From Google)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ1c2.jpg)

Note that I am not specifically going for a pixel-based approach; this is just the only solution I could think of.

Comment: If they block the API during a competitive match, wouldn't this be cheating?

Comment: Reading the pixels On the screen isn't accessing anything in the program in any way; the only time I do that is to get the Process ID, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A much more work intensive way of doing this would be to get runtime information from your machine, i.e. variables and associated values in memory. This would require at least to some degree [reverse engineering](https://blog.udemy.com/reverse-engineering-tutorial/) of the CS:GO client code. But, if you could manage it, I imagine it would be the most reliable way of determining the information you desire. (Be wary of a ban-hammer to the face though.)

Comment: I suppose I could give it a shot, but it would be very tedious, and the CS:GO client is known for its difficulty to hack :(